# Redux-form password validation only after both fields touched

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

Currently on my custom component I'm using an SFC that looks like:

```
export const InputField = field => (
  <div>
    <TextField required={field.required} invalid={field.meta.touched && !!field.meta.error}
     label={field.label} {...field.input} type={field.type} />
    {field.meta.touched && !!field.meta.error && (<TextFieldHelperText persistent
    validationMsg>{field.meta.error}</TextFieldHelperText>)}
  </div>
);
```

(Here TextField and TextFieldHelperText are styled components).

This is all good for text inputs that are only concerned about themselves, but on a Password field, closely followed by a Password confirm field I don't want the field to be marked as invalid until the password confirm field is also touched... but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the password confirm field and say essentially:

```
invalid={field.meta.touched && otherField.meta.touched && !!field.meta.error}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Can you share the component that you're calling this component in?

Comment: Sure... there's more to it but this is the relevant bit (Field is imported from redux-form):
`<Field
                  label="Password" required name="password"
                  component={InputField} props={{ type: 'password' }} />
              </GridCell>
              <GridCell desktop="6">
                <Field
                  label="Password Confirm" required name="passwordConfirm"
                  component={InputField} props={{ type: 'password' }} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap both fields into a wrapper component, use state of the parent component for storing info about touched fields and pass a prop if the validation possible. Something like this

```js
class PassFields extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      passTouched: false,
      passConfirmTouched: false,
    }
  }

  handlePassFocus = (e) => {
    this.setState({ passTouched: true })
  }

  handlePassConfirmFocus = (e) => {
    this.setState({ passConfirmTouched: true })
  }

  render() {
    const canBeValidated = this.state.passTouched && this.state.passConfirmTouched
    return (
        <div className="form">
            <PassField
                {...this.props}
                onFocus={this.handlePassFocus}
                canBeValidated={canBeValidated}
            />
            <PassConfirmField
                {...this.props}
                onFocus={this.handlePassConfirmFocus}
                canBeValidated={canBeValidated}
            />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And you now can use something like this

```html
<TextField 
  required={field.required} 
  invalid={field.canBeValidated && !!field.meta.error}
  onFocus={field.onFocus}
...
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a more redux-form specific way of achieving this... but perhaps not.

Comment: With redux forms propagating props passed into the 'Field' down to the custom component this works with minimal changes to the code sample above. Thanks @Placido!